Retrofit: Simple way to extract response body when HTTP response code is non 200/201
I am using Compose, Flows, clean arch, MVVM and repository pattern.
I don't want to crate any generic classes. I really just want to see a simple GET and POST handled with Loading, Success or Error conditions handled and without the need to copy paste how a HTTP Exception is handled all over the code. When I try to get the errorBody() item from Retrofit, It does not have the body returned by the API. Here is my code:
fun login(email: String, password: String) {
    _loginState.update {
        it.copy(isLoading = true)
    }

//call api here
viewModelScope.launch {
    authRepository.login(email, password).collectLatest { loginResponse ->

        val responseCode = loginResponse.code()
        if (loginResponse.isSuccessful) {
            val token = loginResponse.body()?.access_token ?: ""
            //val refreshToken = loginResponse.body()?.refresh_token ?: ""
            Log.d("Token:", token)


            localUserManager.saveAccessToken(token)
            _loginState.update {
                it.copy(isLoading = false, loginSuccessful = true, errorMessage = "")
            }


        } else {
            val errorBody = loginResponse.errorBody().toString()
            val message = try {
                JSONObject(errorBody).get("reason")
            } catch (e: JSONException) {
                "Unknown API Error"
            }
            val errorMessage = "Error $responseCode: $message"

            _loginState.update {
                it.copy(
                    isLoading = false,
                    loginSuccessful = false,
                    errorMessage = errorMessage
                )
            }
        }

    }
}

For a successful request, I am able to retrieve the access_token from the Response object. When a response has a non 200/201 status code, I am not able to get the body returned by the API. For example, the API returns this response for a non-successful login attempt with status code 401.
{
    "reason": "You entered an invalid email or password.",
    "success": false
}

How can I access the "reason" field from the API when status code is 401? What am I not getting right?

"When I try to get the errorBody() item from Retrofit, It does not have the body returned by the API" -- what does it have? When you log errorBody, what do you get?

It was logging some binary data. I have changed to loginResponse.errorBody().string() instead of toString()  and it seems to give me the String of the response body, which is what I was expecting.
